# Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.) for popupbutton

Tags: dlopen, data-formatters

```
    #0  0x7fff8102a70e in flush_cache
    #1  0x7fff81030605 in flushCaches
    #2  0x7fff8103293c in remethodizeClass
    #3  0x7fff8102372c in _read_images
    #4  0x7fff81039835 in map_images_nolock
    #5  0x7fff810229a0 in map_images
    #6  0x7fff5fc039c5 in __dyld__ZN4dyldL18notifyBatchPartialE17dyld_image_statesbPFPKcS0_jPK15dyld_image_infoE
    #7  0x7fff5fc0c849 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader4linkERKNS_11LinkContextEbbRKNS_10RPathChainE
    #8  0x7fff5fc04d54 in __dyld__ZN4dyld4linkEP11ImageLoaderbRKNS0_10RPathChainE
    #9  0x7fff5fc08f7c in __dyld_dlopen
    #10 0x7fff88d0f360 in dlopen
    #11 0x7fff85aad7b1 in InitShortcut
    #12 0x7fff85aad6b5 in SetupMenuTracking
    #13 0x7fff85bd4511 in PopUpMenuSelectCore
    #14 0x7fff85bd4d02 in _HandlePopUpMenuSelection7
    #15 0x7fff808e9ee3 in _NSSLMPopUpCarbonMenu3
    #16 0x7fff80a99ada in -[NSPopUpButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:]
    #17 0x7fff8081d1c9 in -[NSControl mouseDown:]
    #18 0x7fff807372f7 in -[NSWindow sendEvent:]
    #19 0x7fff8066ca46 in -[NSApplication sendEvent:]
    #20 0x7fff80603476 in -[NSApplication run]
    #21 0x7fff805fc144 in NSApplicationMain
    #22 0x10000100b in main at main.m:13

    The above mentioned is my call stack picked from debugger...
    THe problem is that when I click the pop up button on my running project on mac os 10.6...I get 

    Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
    sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
    Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Not safe to call dlopen at this time.)

I set DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 to get the list of libraries being loaded and I get the following information when I lauch app from terminal....but I don't get any reaction when I click NSPopupbutton button type .....
dyld: loaded: /usr/bin/open
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
```

Please forgive me for excess of information probably I am giving but I hope it help ....
        Rest of the controls work just fine but only popupbutton is type of button causing trouble. Can someone please suggest me some solution.!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution to this problem technically but I am writing how I dealt with the problem.
My app was running well on leopard and faulty on snow leopard so I created a .xcconfig from the running xcode version and gave it as build settings to my project and it worked great.
It was more of escaping the problem's complexity but at times we are short of time . Hope it helps...!!